# In Atom: What does the little red triangle and dotted line tell me?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

What does this indicator on line 53 tell me? It's not an error but ...

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is git diff. It means that lines have been deleted at this point.